# Maintain order as original document while using addToSet in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I read the documentation and found that addToSet doesn't guarantee order.
But is there any way I can preserve the order as the original document.
My Query is :-

```
    aggregate([{$match: {
      $or:[{"Name.No":"119"},{"Name.No":"120"}]
    }}, {$project: {
      x:{$objectToArray:"$Results"}
    }},{$unwind: "$x"},{$group: {_id: "$x.k", distinctVals: {$addToSet: "$x.v.TCR"}}}])
```

Sample Data:

```
{"Name" : {"No." : "119","Time" : "t"},
"Results":{"K1" : {"Counters" : x, "TCR" : [{"Name" : "K11", "Result" : "PASSED"}, 
                                             {"Name" : "K12","Result" : "FAILED"},
                                             {"Name" : "K13","Result" : "PASSED"}]
                    },
            "K2" : {"Counters": y, "TCR" : [{"Name" : "K21","Result" : "PASSED"},              
                                            {"Name" : "K22","Result" : "PASSED"}]
                      
                    }
            
           }
}
```

}
Job2;

```
 {"Name" : {"No." : "120","Time" : "t1"},
"Results":{"K1" : {"Counters" : x, "TCR" : [{"Name" : "K11", "Result" : "PASSED"}, 
                                             {"Name" : "K12","Result" : "PASSED"},
                                             {"Name" : "K13","Result" : "FAILED"}]
                    },
            "K3" : {"Counters": y, "TCR" : [{"Name" : "K31","Result" : "PASSED"},              
                                            {"Name" : "K32","Result" : "PASSED"}]
                      
                    }
            
           
}
```

}
Expected;

```
 {"Name" : {"No." : "119-120","Time" : "lowest(t,t1)"},
"Results":{"K1" : {"Counters" : x, "TCR" : [{"Name" : "K11", "Result" : "PASSED"}, 
                                             {"Name" : "K12","Result" : "PASSED"},
                                             {"Name" : "K13","Result" : "PASSED"}]
                    },
            "K2" : {"Counters": y, "TCR" : [{"Name" : "K21","Result" : "PASSED"},              
                                            {"Name" : "K22","Result" : "PASSED"}]
                      
                    },
             "K3" : {"Counters": y, "TCR" : [{"Name" : "K31","Result" : "PASSED"},              
                                            {"Name" : "K32","Result" : "PASSED"}]
                      
                    }
            
           
}
```

}
I want to maintain the order same as original document, also every time document would change,so I cant sort based on any parameter.

Comment: Can you add a sample data with your query https://mongoplayground.net/

Comment: How do you define the order? Let's assume you input is `[20, 10, 20]`. What output do you like to get? `[10, 20]` or `[20,10]`? Solution from @turivishal gives `[20,10]`

Comment: Added sample data now in question.

Answer (score 0):

- convert Results object to array format using `$objectToArray`
- `$unwind` deconstruct `Results` array
- `$unwind` deconstruct `Results.v.TCR` array
- `$match` to filter `PASSED` Result
- `$group` by `Results.k` and get first `Name`, get first `Counters`, construct array of `Results.v.TCR`
- `$group` by null and get minimum `Time`, construct unique array of `No`, construct `Results` array in key-value pair, `$reduce` to iterate loop of `TCR` and remove duplicate documents
- `$project` to show required fields, convert `Results` array to object using `$arrayToObject`, convert No array to string and concat with "-"

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $addFields: { Results: { $objectToArray: "$Results" } } },
  { $unwind: "$Results" },
  { $unwind: "$Results.v.TCR" },
  { $match: { "Results.v.TCR.Result": "PASSED" } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$Results.k",
      Name: { $first: "$Name" },
      Counters: { $first: "$Results.v.Counters" },
      TCR: { $push: "$Results.v.TCR" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      Time: { $min: "$Name.Time" },
      No: { $addToSet: "$Name.No" },
      Results: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id",
          v: {
            Counters: "$Counters",
            TCR: {
              $reduce: {
                input: "$TCR",
                initialValue: [],
                in: {
                  $cond: [
                    {
                      $in: [
                        {
                          Name: "$$this.Name",
                          Result: "$$this.Result"
                        },
                        "$$value"
                      ]
                    },
                    "$$value",
                    {
                      $concatArrays: [
                        "$$value",
                        [
                          {
                            Name: "$$this.Name",
                            Result: "$$this.Result"
                          }
                        ]
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      Results: { $arrayToObject: "$Results" },
      Name: {
        Time: "$Time",
        No: {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$No",
            initialValue: "",
            in: {
              $concat: [
                "$$value",
                { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$$value", ""]}, "", "-"] },
                "$$this"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/N8x08rcs0Hf)

> The "." (dot) in "No." field is not valid, it may cause issue in mongodb query operations, i would suggest do not use "." (dot) as field name.

Comment: no..still not working,, push also didnt retain the order.

Comment: can you post sample document and expected result in your question.

Comment: Updated ques with sample data

Comment: your document is not valid as per your query, are you sure `Results` is already array?, because you have converted it from object to array using `x:{$objectToArray:"$Results"}` so $project stage is not needed.

Comment: could you please check now

Comment: actually its same as per your expected result. can you explain *still not working for me* will not help.

Comment: it did merge the results, but still order is not getting preserved. Eg, in example, order should be in Results ( K1, K2, K3), but with this it doesn't guarantee me this order, it is random order like (K2, K1 ,K3)  or K3, K1,K2

Comment: i don't think this is possible when you merge multiple documents, my query will always return as per data (K11,K13,K12), because match condition will remove other result and it return (K11,K13) from first document and from second document (K12) so query will merge both result in sequence (K11,K13) + (K12) = (K11,K13,K12).

Comment: i would suggest you to do this in your programming language, or if you want to do this in your query you can use [$function](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) or  [$accumulator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/accumulator/index.html) operators you can write js code, but these are very expensive for query performance.